# SSRS report Group by rows in the Display

Tags: reporting-services

I want to group by rows below in SSRS Report:

```
LastName FirstName  EmployeeID  Day         WorkHours 
Gaines   Edward     77430       Monday      8
Gaines   Edward     77430       Tuesday     10
Gaines   Edward     77430       Wednesday   9
```

Display in the report should look like:

```
LastName    FirstName   EmployeeID  Day         WorkHours
                                    Monday      8
Gaines      Edward      77430       Tuesday     10
                                    Wednesday   7
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please do proper formatting of your post as this will help people to answer it.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add a **table** to your report. Add the **Day** and **Work hours** fields to the **Data** part of the table.

Right-click on the Row header box and **Add Group** -> **Parent Group**.

[image: Add Parent Group]

Add your **EmployeeID** field to the new column on the left. Then add a new column for **First Name** by right-clicking on the column header and **Insert Column -> Left**. Repeat for **Last Name**.